# Camel route multiple files

Tags: file, apache-camel, sftp

How does one pass multiple files through a pojo that fetches them and then to a file component, and to a ftp in one route?
I've been trying to use a Map but not to sure what the body should have for key name, what should GetFiles do to pass on multiple files in below example? If a map should be returned what keys should that map hold?

```
from("mock:start")
    .to(GetFiles.class)
    .to("file:transfer/outbound")
    .to("sftp:{{sftp_uri}}");
```

Comment: Usually a route would process one file at a time and each message would have a GenericFile (a camel object which represents a file) as it's body. Do you have a specific requirement to process files in batches or to send the files all together via sftp? Also is GetFiles getting the files from the file system or is it getting data from somewhere else and putting it into files? If it's from the file system it might be easier to use `from("file:///location/of/files")` which is an example of the file component as a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just drop the files into a folder, have one route without any Java?

from("file:///inbound").multicast().to("file:outbound/", "sftp://");